# Remain connected to wifi network that has a captive portal

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, captivenetwork

There's a wireless network I'm connecting to using my iOS device. In order to access the internet, a captive portal page is displayed prompting for a username and password. I would like my device to ignore that page and remain connected to the wireless lan. I don't mind if I can't get on to the internet - I just want to connect to another device on the wifi network. I can do this on other devices (android, laptops etc), it's just iOS devices that seem to enforce a "use captive portal or be disconnected" policy.

So, is there a way for my iOS device to remain connected to a wifi lan that has a captive portal?

Answer (score 2):

This is a well-known problem with iOS. Apple assumes, incorrectly in my view, that any iOS Wi-Fi connected device must access the Internet and must be able to reach Apple's servers (of which there are dozens, only one of which is apple.com).

The device chooses a server apparently randomly from a list and attempts to load a specific HTML file in a random file path from the chosen server.

If the device is connected to the Wi-Fi access point but can't reach Apple, iOS assumes that the user has not logged into the access point and thus must be shown the captive portal login page.

This has caused grief to developers who want the user device only to access web resources on the local network, where no Internet access is provided or needed; and when the access point is open with no login required. The captive portal page just confuses the user.

The solution is to spoof the Apple servers. The only way I know of is to configure a web server to note certain nonrandom content in the HTTP attempts from the user device, and to supply the file the device is looking for. This is how the LibraryBox and PirateBox do it. Check LibraryBox.us.